# how to change background image color without changing background

Tags: css

I have a chevron in white color. Based on titles I want to change the color to black. I tried filter but it gets applied to both *background*  and *background-image*. How can I change the chevron to black by applying some kind of filter only to *background-image*?

```
    background-color: #cdfdfd;
    text-align: left !important;
    background-position-x: right;
    background-image: url(chevron-right-v2.svg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border-radius: 0.7vw;
    transition: background-color 250ms;
    background-position-y: center;
    color: #282828;
```

[image: image for reference]

Comment: Is it ok to change the image type, or do you only use SVG?

Comment: please include all your codes

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you can apply filters to a background image itself, but there is a workaround for this.

Use `:before` element and give it `height` and `width` of 100% and the background-image,
now you can apply a filter to this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this helps or not, but if you look at W3School `background-image: url("chevron-right-v2.svg")`, you have to put quotes in the url

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-image.asp